# Unable to program STM32 using ST Link utility: programming error @: 0x00000001

Tags: stm32

I have been trying to get my grips around programming STM32. I have got a Nornir developed Dash7/sensor board (for which absolutely no documentation exists somehow...), which has a STM32L100RBT6 MCU. So I'd like to program my own software for this board.

So far I have succesfully made a project and build the firmware. At this point I am trying to flash the .hex file onto the MCU using a official ST-link v2 programmer, in combination with the ST-Link utility software (under windows 10). I am using the JTAG interface on the board.

In the ST-link utility, I can connect to the board, and read it out. I have erased the chip, and I only read zeros in the memory, for both memory pages (0x00000000 and 0x08000000).

When I try `Target > Program` it however, after selecting my .hex file and hitting Start, the console tells me:

```
16:54:48 : Connected via JTAG.
16:54:48 : Connection mode : Normal.
16:54:48 : Debug in Low Power mode enabled.
16:54:49 : Device ID:0x416 
16:54:49 : Device flash Size : 128KBytes
16:54:49 : Device family :STM32L100x8/L15xx8
16:54:52 : Memory programmed in 0s and 250ms.
```

But when I read out the memory, it is not programmed. It only shows me zeros on both pages (0x00000000 and 0x08000000).

When I select `Target > Program & Verify`, I get a error message 'programming error @: 0x00000001' and the following console output:

```
16:55:39 : Connected via JTAG.
16:55:39 : Connection mode : Normal.
16:55:39 : Debug in Low Power mode enabled.
16:55:39 : Device ID:0x416 
16:55:39 : Device flash Size : 128KBytes
16:55:39 : Device family :STM32L100x8/L15xx8
16:56:16 : No OnChip verification function found. Verify after programming will be performed.
16:56:17 : Programming error @: 0x00000001
```

My memory linker script (mem.ld) is as follows:

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
  RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 10K

  /*
   * Optional sections; define the origin and length to match
   * the the specific requirements of your hardware. The zero
   * length prevents inadvertent allocation.
   */
  CCMRAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0
  FLASHB1 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0
  EXTMEMB0 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0
  EXTMEMB1 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0
  EXTMEMB2 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0
  EXTMEMB3 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0
}
```

I am stuck at this point, and have so far been unable to find any resources pointing me in the right direction. Any ideas?

Comment: The Flash starting address is `0x08000000` for STM32, if the error is at `0x00000001` there is a possibility that you want to flash your program to the wrong place. There is an `Address:` field in ST-Link Utility, please tell me what address is visible in that?

Comment: Just look at the first two lines of your .hex file, it should look like :02000004**0800**F2 <- there, 0800 is the high-order half of the starting address, 
:10**0000**00FC3F0120A50A0008C90D0008950C000856 <- 0000 is the lower half. If there is something else, then your program is linked at the wrong address.

Comment: Adding your memory linker script would be helpful.

Comment: First two lines are  :10000000**0028**0020... and :10**0010**00D9010000..., so I guess it is not linked correctly

Comment: after fixing the mem.ld address to 0x08000000, and changing to the correct gcc-arm-none-eabi compiler (oeps), the hex file now looks correct: :02000004**0800**F2
:10**0000**00002800205901000861010008650100086E, but error in ST-link utility remains

Comment: reloading the .hex file into ST-link utility suddenly solved it. Old .hex was still somewhere in memory? It is solved now. Answer was solving a combination of mistakes I made (compiler, mem.ld, reloading .hex in ST-link utility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ST Link utilty caches the files that you use. It's not documented anywhere but it does this. If you want to be 100% sure you've programmed the latest binary/hex file change the name of the file (from the previous version) and program again